# emf of a moving wire in a variable magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, classical-electrodynamics

Lets, say that Magnetic filed is either (case 1) $B=B_0$ or (case 2) $B=B_0\sin{\frac{\pi x}{L}}$in $z$ direction. We have a wire with a length of $L$ along $y$ axis which is moving in $x$ direction and its position is $x$.

For the case 1, when $B$ is constant ($B=B_0$), we know that $\text{emf}=B_0 L \frac{dx}{dt}$.

But what would happen in case 2? My own explanation is that since there is no loop when there is no movement, we can say that $\text{emf}=B_0L \frac{dx}{dt}\sin{\frac{\pi x}{L}}$.
In other words I do not care about the rate of change of field and what I need to know is only its value at any time. Am I right here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your wire loop is thin and the charges stay in the wire, then the magnetic EMF is entirely equal to the line integral of the magnetic force per unit charge from the instantaneous magnetic field (regardless of whether or how the magnetic field is changing), line integrated along the wire. When the wire is thin, and the charges stay in the wire then you can relate that magnetic force to the magnetic field and the velocity of the wire. But the change in the magnetic doesn't affect the magnetic EMF.

And the electric EMF is always entirely equal to the flux of $-\partial \vec B/\partial t$ through the area enclosed by the instantaneous location of the wire loop (regardless of the motion, if any, of the wire).

So the magnetic EMF only cares about the velocity of the wire and the magnetic field now (with no regard for how the magnetic field is changing). And the electric EMF cares about the flux of the $-\partial \vec B/\partial t$ right now, and doesn't care about the motion of the wire (except as the motion of the wire might be involved in Hall type voltages to keep the charges inside the wire).

This is becasue the magnetic force depends on the motion and the magnetic field. And the electric force doesn't care about the motion but it does depend on the electric field now. And the electric field now is related to $-\partial \vec B/\partial t$ now.

> In my problem B is only a function of x and not time ($B=B_0\sin{\frac{\pi x}{L}}$), So I think this means that E=0 at all locations as $\nabla\times E=-\partial \vec B/\partial t=0$, giving me a zero electric emf.

Now that I've addressed one confusion, note that the $\vec B$ field you list has a nonzero curl, so unless the electric current balances it perfectly, your electric field has a nonzero change in time. Which means it could only be zero for an instant.

Plus, normally you have forces acting on the non mobile charges to stress the wire and forces acting on the mobile charges that influence the current. In your case the forces are not pushing current through the wire. They have places where they are positive and places where negative so charge is building up where current flows from both sides. And when you have charge buildup it seems strange to assert there is no electric field, and in fact by Gauss it must have a nonzero electric field.

The reason issue is that you simply can't make up just any solution to a magnetic field and then assert it is static. And just having a finite segment of wire doesn't make it clear what you mean an EMF or which loop that site is a intended to be part of.

You didn't specify the electric field, and even if it were instantaneously zero it wouldn't stay that way.

So you could ask yourself whether it is possible to have a static magnetic field like you propose. You can have an instantaneous magnetic field like that since the divergence is zero ($\vec \nabla \cdot \vec B=\vec \nabla \cdot B_0 \sin (kx)\hat z=0$). And you could have an instantaneously zero electric field if you'd like to if everything is instantaneously charge neutral ($\vec \nabla \cdot \vec E=\vec \nabla \cdot \vec 0=0=\rho/\epsilon_0$). And if there were no electric current instantaneously then you get a changing electric field from the nonzero curl of the magnetic field: $$\frac{\partial \vec E}{\partial t}=\frac{1}{\epsilon_0}\left(-\vec J+\frac{1}{\mu_0}\vec \nabla \times \vec B\right)$$ $$=\frac{1}{\epsilon_0}\left(-\vec 0-\frac{1}{\mu_0}kB_0\cos(kx)\hat y\right)\neq \vec 0.$$

And worse, lets look at the second time derivative of $\vec B:$
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\vec B=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial \vec B}{\partial t}$$ $$=-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\vec \nabla \times \vec E$$ $$=-\vec \nabla \times \frac{\partial \vec E}{\partial t}$$
$$=-\vec \nabla \times \frac{1}{\epsilon_0}\left(-\vec J+\frac{1}{\mu_0}\vec \nabla \times \vec B\right)$$

So
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\vec B=\frac{1}{\epsilon_0}\vec \nabla \times \vec J-+\frac{1}{\epsilon_0\mu_0}\vec \nabla \times
(\vec \nabla \times \vec B).$$

And the second curl of $\vec B$ is not zero. So your wire would have to have just the right current to keep that second derivative zero, so the magnetic field is unlikely to be static. And if there is empty space where the wire is moving into there isn't a current there, so the magnetic field **is** going to change in time.

So it looks like your assumption just violates the laws of physics.

Comment: so you agree that $\text{emf}=B_0L \frac{dx}{dt}\sin{\frac{\pi x}{L}}$? Right?

Comment: @Sathyam Incorrect. The **electric** EMF equals $\oint \vec E\cdot d\vec \ell$ and the magnetic EMF equals $\oint \left(\vec u\times\vec B\right) \cdot d\vec \ell$ and for a thin wire whose charges stay in the wire you can relate that $u$ to the motion $v$ of the wire. But sure the circulation of E is related to the flux of the time derivative of B.

Comment: @EhsanAsadi Not at all. The total EMF equals the sum of the electric EMF and the magnetic EMF. You are simply computing the force per unit charge due to the magnetic force, and neglecting that there is probably an electric force as well.

Comment: @Timaeus Comment was based on a blind spot. Revered.

Comment: Thank you a lot, now I understand the different between magnetic emf and electric emf.
In my problem B is only a function of x and not time ($B=B_0\sin{\frac{\pi x}{L}}$), So I think this means that E=0 at all locations as $\nabla\times E=-\partial \vec B/\partial t=0$, giving me a zero electric emf. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Timaeus: Indeed, $$\int_C (\mathbf v \times \mathbf B)\cdot d\mathbf s+ \int_C \mathbf E\cdot d\mathbf s= -\frac{d\Phi}{dt}\;.$$ Both EMFs are related to the negative change of magnetic flux.

Comment: @Timaeus: Check the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction#Proof_of_Faraday.27s_law) derivation.

Comment: @EhsanAsadi Your situation can't happen. See my edit.

Comment: @user36790 I responded to the wrong person. My apologies.

Comment: @Timaeus: I did not know that "you simply can't make up just any solution to a magnetic field and then assert it is static". I was trying to simplify my questions here but it did not work!
I have an electrical linear machine, magnetic field that I measured in radial direction ($B_r$) is periodic which is produced by magnets on the stationary part. Around the magnets, I a single wire. I want to know how much force will be experienced by the wire that is short circuit to itself. Wire is located at radius $r$ where values of $B_x$ are zero and further due to symmetry $B_{\theta}=0$.

Comment: @EhsanAsadi Even that is too vague. You want a force. Do you want a force in the mobile charges of the wire, driving s current. Or do you want the force on the non mobile parts (to find the tension and expansion of the wire). Or the resistance to your attempt to move it?